# Detect custom user meta change in Woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

So I have the script below that is functioning perfectly. It counts everything correctly, notifies the user correctly and is essentially exactly what I want to happen:

It is a tier rewards system that updates once a customer makes XX amount of purchases, and once a tier is advanced a modal window pops up notifying them of their advancement with a "Congratulations!"

The issue is - the way it works is, if the customer has say 5 orders (a tier advancement amount) and uses a different browser, they will receive this notification again (as the dismissal is done in Javascript and stored in a cookie). If cookie doesnt exist or they are private browsing, they will see this message over and over.

I would like a more permanent and effective way of detecting whether the user has seen this advancement message, and only show them to modal time.

```
// -----------------------------------------
// COUNT AMOUNT UNTIL CUSTOMER REACHES NEXT TIER
function amount_until_tier() {
    $count = count_orders();
    $tier_name = tier_status();

    //$amount_until = abs($count - $next_tier);

    if ( $count >= 50 ) {
        echo 'You\'ve made it! You\'re VIP. Expect random rewards.';
    } else {
        //echo 'You need <strong>' . $amount_until . '</strong> more orders to reach <strong>' . $tier_name . '</strong>';
    }

    $the_digits = ['5','15','30','50'];

    $showModal = false;

    if (in_array($count, $the_digits)) {
        if (!isset( $_COOKIE["tier_advance"] )) {
            $showModal= true;
        } else {
            if ($_COOKIE["tier_advance"] != "$count") {
                $showModal = true;
            } else {
                // echo "false because tier_advance !== count
            }
        } 
    } else {
        // echo "false because not in the_digits";
    }

    if ($showModal) {
          echo '<script>
                    jQuery(window).on("load",function(){
                        jQuery("#tier_advance").modal("show");
                    });
                    jQuery(document).on("click", "#tier_confirm", function(){            
                        // Set a cookie
                        Cookies.set("tier_advance", "' . $count . '", { expires: 356 });
                    });

            </script>
            
            <!-- BEGIN Share Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="tier_advance" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <h5>CONGRATULATIONS!' . $count . '</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body text-center">
                  <p>You are now a <strong class="all-caps"> ' . $tier_name . ' </strong>tier customer!</p>
                  <p>Expect some sweet rewards to start coming your way!</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer modal-footer-centered">
                    <button id="tier_confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Awesome, thanks!</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END Share Modal -->';
    }        
}

add_action('wp_head', 'amount_until_tier');
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say in the title, one possibility is to save the tier data in the user profile.
In order to not rely on cookies, you can make an [ajax request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/) to the server to signal the dismissal of the modal (I've removed some code for brevity, check the comments):

```
function amount_until_tier() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $count = count_orders();
    $tier_name = tier_status();

    // REMOVED ($count >= 50) check

    $the_digits = ['5','15','30','50'];

    $showModal = false;

    if (in_array($count, $the_digits)) {
        $dismissed_tier = $current_user->get('last_dismissed_tier');
    
        if ($dismissed_tier != $tier_name) {
            $showModal = true;
        }
    }

    if ($showModal) {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(window).on("load",function(){
            jQuery("#tier_advance").modal("show");
        });
        
        jQuery(document).on("click", "#tier_confirm", function(){    
            <?php $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>        
            jQuery.ajax("<?= $ajax_url; ?>", {action: 'dismiss_tier_modal'})
            .then(() => jQuery("#tier_advance").modal("hide"));
        });
    </script>
    <!-- MODAL HTML HERE -->
    <?php
    }        
}
add_action('wp_head', 'amount_until_tier');

// Create the ajax action to dismiss the modal
function ajax_dismiss_tier_modal_action()
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Save current tier as last shown
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_dismissed_tier', tier_status());
} 
// Register the ajax action for logged-in users only
add_action('wp_ajax_dismiss_tier_modal', 'ajax_dismiss_tier_modal_action');
```

You could also store the current tier and update it after an order is completed, but that would require you to update your existing users.